# Dense set in an infinite cofinite space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite cofinite space and let $A \subset X$ be infinite. Then $\overline A = X$

I am having a tough time in trying to understand this. Why is every infinite set in an infinite cofinite space dense ?

Comment: So just to be clear, $X$ is an infinite set equipped with the cofinite topology?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x \in X$. Let $O$ be an open set that contains $x$. This means that $X \setminus O$ is finite. If $O$ does not intersect $A$, then $A \subseteq X \setminus O$, which is finite and as $A$ is infinite, this cannot happen. So $O$ intersects $A$. As $O$ was an arbitary neighbourhood of $x$, $x \in \overline{A}$. As $x$ was arbitrary, $\overline{A} = X$.

Another way to look at it: the only closed sets of $X$ are the finite ones and $X$. As $\overline{A}$ is a closed set that contains $A$, $\overline{A}$ cannot be finite, so it must be $X$.

Comment: Why can't any infinite set be closed in $X$ ?

Comment: @johny All closed sets are exactly the complements of open sets. All open sets are the empty set (which gives $X$ as a closed set, the only infinite closed set) and all sets $O$ with $X \setminus O$ finite, and their complement is exactly those finite sets $X \setminus O$. So all other closed sets are finite.